# React Props to Pass Large Set of Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a scenario where i want to first make a request and validate the response from the server and then show UI. Complete Response also needs to be passed in the component.  I have sample code and i got the proper response from server but it does not get passed to the component. I am using props to pass data to Component. How can i achieve this ?

index.tsx

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { CarsGrid } from "./CarsGrid";


const init = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json"
    )
    return await response.json();

  } catch (err) {}
};

function App() {
  init().then(result=> {
    console.log('Correct Response is printed',result);
    return <CarsGrid gridRows={result} />;
  });
  return (<></>)
}

export default App;
```

React Component

```js
export function CarsGrid({gridRows}) {
console.log('Data gridRows', gridRows);
})
```

But results does not get printed in `console.log('Data gridRows', gridRows);` though response is printed at `console.log('Correct Response is printed',result);`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The return in your code:

```js
init().then(result=> {
  console.log('Correct Response is printed',result);
  return <CarsGrid gridRows={result} />;
});
```

is returning for the callback passed to `then`, not as the rendering result of your App function/component.

So the `init().then()` part is not contributing to the rendering process. This is as if your App code was:

```js
function App() {
  return (<></>)
}
```

And so your `CarsGrid` function is never executed.

A "react" way would be to rely on a state and to fetch your data in an effect:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/row-data.json"
        );
        const result = await response.json();

        console.log('Correct Response is printed',result);

        setData(result);
      } catch (err) {}
    };

    init();
  }, []);

  return data && <CarsGrid gridRows={data} />;
}
```

Comment: your approach is correct but i cannot use this. Because i want to analyze the output in init().then() and depending on the result, i may show another UI. ( AeroplaneGrid )

Comment: @Raj this approach is still correct. If you want to render different components, depending on the result of your async call, then you just need to encode this in the state and use conditional rendering: `data.whatEverFieldMakesTheDistinction ? <CarsGrid /> : <AeroplaneGrid />`.

Comment: @David, I agree with you. Your solution will work. But still i want to use init().then()

Comment: @Raj you want, but you can't...